# Tkinter font size not consistent on different screens

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, fonts, pyinstaller, display

So I have made demo program with a gui using tkkbootsrap a skin of tkinter. My demo works fine however when i use pyinstaller to extract the file into an exe and run it on another computer some of the scaling is wrong. Most things scale fine except for any text boxes I used (you can see the difference in my images below).

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY1lB.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V2wb.png)

I have locked the geometry to a set display size and disabled rezising however that hasn't fixed it. Is there either a way to make sure that the scaling never happens in the first place or is there a way to adjust the font size by reading the display size or resolution.

Thanks

Comment: The other PC may have different system *scaling* parameter.

Comment: I think you nailed it do you know if there is a way to pull what scaling parameter a pc is running so I can adjust the font size accordingly.